# Get coordinates of image in ImageBox after centering?

Tags: c#, image, coordinates, visual-studio-2015

I have an image loaded into an ImageBox. The ImageBox is anchored Top, Bottom, Left, and Right. In addition, the `SizeMode` attribute is set to `CenterImage`.

In addition, my form is set to maximize on load.

I need to get the top left coordinate of the image. The image resizes when the form maximizes, and it also centers, which makes the coordinates change.

Am I making sense? How can I find these coordinates?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? This is not a please code this for me site.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The true conundrum is to get the coordinates relative to the window itself, so I am adding the `location` property of the ImageBox itself to my coordinates, but I couldn't find a property for its position after it is centered.

Comment: Write code under form resize event. X1:image1.Left, Y1:image1.Top, X2:image1.Width-image1.Left, Y2:image1.Height-image1.Top. That way.

Comment: The `Screen` class will get you the size of the monitor.  Your WinForm has a `Size` and `Location` property.  You can get the size of the image from the `PictureBox` control.  I'm sure you can figure out the math.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the center of the picturebox by dividing its width/height by 2.  Subtract from those x/y values, half the width/height of the image within it:

```
    private void pictureBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(pictureBox1.Width / 2 - pictureBox1.Image.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Height / 2 - pictureBox1.Image.Height / 2);
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(pt, pictureBox1.Image.Size);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rc);
    }
```